# Getting a better code? Having a while inside a foreach - is this a good way for doing so?

Tags: php, zend-framework, rss, feed

I intend to list the last 2 title entries of a news feed where a given tag is something.

Assuming that the getCategories() and getValues() are working methods. (they are).

Can anyone help to produce a better code then this one?

(I'm not even sure if that foreach inside logic will work...);

```
$feedUrl = 'http://www.abc.org/?feed=rss2';

$feed = Zend_Feed_Reader::import($feedUrl);

$lastNews = array();

   foreach ($feed as $key=>$entry)
   {
       if (in_array('tag A', $entry->getCategories()->getValues()))
       {
          while ($key < 2)
          {
             $lastNews['title'] = $entry->getTitle();
             $lastNews['link'] = $entry->getLink();
          }
       }
   }
```

**UPDATE:**
If I remove the while part, I get all ALL feed entries with the respective title and link. 
Ok.

What I want to achieve however, is having just TWO entries with their respective title and link parts.

Add - The two entries must be the most recent. But, I'm hopping the the order of the foreach to work, will give me the most recent ones as the first keys. (not sure however).

**UPDATE II:**

Based on @Dereleased I know have this:

(I have just added the [] part)

```
$okEntries = 0;
foreach ($feed as $key => $entry) {
  if ($okEntries >= 2) {
    break;
  }

  if (in_array('Tag A', $entry->getCategories()->getValues()))
  {
     $lastNews[]['title'] = $entry->getTitle();
     $lastNews[]['link'] = $entry->getLink();
     ++$okEntries;
   }
}
```

I'm getting this:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(65) "test title A"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["link"]=>
    string(33) "http://www.linkA.com"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(80) "Test title B"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    ["link"]=>
    string(33) "http://www.linkB.com"
  }
}
```

Now, the array[0] and [1] are a title link group, and the array[2] and [3] are the second array group, how can I have those as two groups ?

Thanks in advance,
MEM

Comment: No one is here to hurt your feelings, and if they are, they dont belong here. That's not what StackOverflow is all about.

Comment: Doesn't that break out with a single entry returned (the first entry) on the first past (assuming the keys start from 0)?

Comment: Perhaps. Can you please help me to get it better. Actually this is not a function. :) I will remove the return part of this.

Comment: I think the `while ($key < 2)` will cause an infinite loop.  change it to `if ($key < 2)` maybe?

Comment: @Dereleased - I want to list 2 pairs of $lastNews tittle and link, so, I need to somehow loop. Since I want only two of then, I thought while would be a good solution...? How... I see... so the loop will be made by the foreach. And the if will run until $key is less then 2.  Right?

Comment: @barfoon before you are quick to judge you should probably take a look at his questions. @MEM perhaps you should learn not to be so heartfelt over what people type / say online.

Comment: @Brad F Jacobs - I have change the title. I was being ironic with my dummy questions. But np. ;)

Comment: @MEM Your current incarnation - change the two lines with `$lastNews[][..]` to a single `$lastNews[] = array('title' => $entry->getTitle(), 'link' => $entry->getLink());`.  Note that the way you have it, it'll get the first two entries from the feed, not the last two as you requested.

Comment: I updated my response to hopefully do what you want, getting the LAST two not the FIRST two.  Sorry about the indexing error, though, I totally goofed on that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never used this module, so I'm not 100% sure, but logically I think this is what you want:

```
$feedUrl = 'http://www.abc.org/?feed=rss2';
$feed = Zend_Feed_Reader::import($feedUrl);

$lastNews = array();
$okEntries = 0;
foreach ($feed,true as $key => $entry) {
    if ($okEntries >= 2) {
        break;
    }
    if (in_array('tag A', $entry->getCategories()->getValues())) {
        $lastNews[$okEntries]['title'] = $entry->getTitle();
        $lastNews[$okEntries]['link'] = $entry->getLink();
        ++$okEntries;
    }
}
```

#### Edit: didn't realize you wanted the LAST two, but this should do it.

Comment: If I do a foreach with an echo, I get the titles and links of all entries, by a given tag. That's nice. What I want is, instead of having ALL of the entries listed, I would like to have just two of them. - Is this more clear? I will update my question as well. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: The only problem with this code that I can see is that I thought he asked for the *last* two entries.

Comment: I've updated my response, I think this will do what you want.

Comment: Actually, to retrieve the LAST news, its the same as retrieve as first elements on our foreach. So, The one without the reverse array will fit well. ;) Thanks a LOT! :)

Comment: @MEM I take it the feed is in the reverse order then, most recent (ie. "last" first) - you should mention that, lol.

Answer (score 4):

Well there's the insane one-liner approach:

```
$feedUrl = 'http://www.abc.org/?feed=rss2';

$feed = Zend_Feed_Reader::import($feedUrl);

return array_map(create_function('$cEntry',
                                 'return array("title" => $cEntry->getTitle(),
                                               "link" => $cEntry->getLink());'),
                 array_slice(array_filter($feed,
                                          create_function('$cEntry',
                                                          'return in_array("tag A",
                                                                           $cEntry->getCategories()->getValues());')),
                             -2, 2));
```

But that might fail if there are less than two matching entries available, depending on how array_slice() handled there being less entries than requested, I forget.

The best method is probably using XPath on the feed, which is an XML query language.

This is an example, completely untested, it may not parse and the XPath may be slightly wrong for your feed.

```
$feedUrl = 'http://www.abc.org/?feed=rss2';

$feed = Zend_Feed_Reader::import($feedUrl);

$feedXPath = $feed->getXpath();

$targetData = array();
foreach ($feedXPath->evaluate("//item[string(category)='tag A' and position()>=last()-1]" as $cEntry) {
    $targetData[] = array('title' => $feedXPath->evaluate('string(title)', $cEntry),
                          'link' => $feedXPath->evaluate('string(link)', $cEntry));
}

return $targetData;
```

Comment: @Orbling - Do you believe that removing the foreach and the while, and adding a for, will be a good idea?

Comment: array_slice is pretty good at handling fewer entries than expected, no worries.  create_function, however, is REALLY AWESOME at being at least six times slower than standard functions and closures.  Still, kudos for the "insane one-liner" approach, those are always fun.

Comment: @MEM The main issue with your current code, apart from the little errors, is that you are assuming you have to plough through the entire list to get to the end.  You can just attack the end directly.

Comment: @Dereleased Cheers, that means the code will probably be fine.  The `array_*` approach is just an example of what can be done, not necessarily a suggestion.  Zend_Feed_Reader generates an XML DOM, there are better approaches.

Comment: @Dereleased ...and yes, `create_function()` is slower than writing a proper function performance-wise, but I tend to write in functional languages a lot and get used to lambda/anonymous functions.  Cluttering up the namespace with loads of annoying one-time use code affairs is irritating.

Comment: One day, I would be able to understand what you and Dereleased talked. :s I have choose the option that I could better understand not necessarily the best because, that, I cannot evaluate. Thanks a LOT for your feedback. I will mark your answer as usefull. K Regards.

Comment: @MEM Yes, I thought you would choose Dereleased's answer as it was the simplest and thus the most clear example code.  As you asked for better ways, I showed you alternative approaches rather than a fix of what you were doing.  The idea being not for you to use them so much as broaden your experience and perhaps give ideas to others answering.

Comment: Indeed, the ways Orbling posted are definitely ways with which you should become acquainted; the insane one-liner approach shows an excellent command of available PHP functions (which will generally run faster than something you handroll that does the same thing since they are compiled) and array concepts, and the XPath method is important because it gives you powerful XML selectors to work with.  In this particular instance my method was straightforward, but it is less adaptable (without writing inordinate amounts of more code) to changing situations.  Stick with it and you'll get there!